# Brave tracer context becoming null when an error is thrown

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-sleuth

I am testing my traceId webfilter after moving to spring 2.7. using spring cloud sleuth brave 3.1.7.

TracerContext exists up until the exception is thrown from the api, after that tracer context is coming as null. Tracer context is also available throughout when the api is returning 200 OK response

I am doing this in my webfilter

```
response.beforeCommit(() -> {

    final ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();         
    
     final Span currentSpan = tracer.currentSpan(); // span is null in case of Mono.error from API

});
```